# How to fix 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin .Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.' in scala as backend

Tags: scala, cors, same-origin-policy

I am using angularjs in my front-end and this is the piece of code where i call my loclhost , todo variable should have the value , but i get error

Failed to load http://localhost:8080/Cart/1: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

When i use it directly i got the json value.

```
var cartResource = $resource('http://localhost:8080/Cart/:cartId',
{cartId: '@id'});
  $scope.cart1 = cartResource.get({cartId: 1},function(todo) {
                 // success
                console.log("k","k")
             }, function(errResponse) {
                 console.log("nooooo",errResponse)
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

You might probably enable the CORS filter on your backend! If your backend server is Play Framework, here is some documentation on how this is done:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/CorsFilter

Comment: This is my first steps in scala so  i just followed the steps https://danielasfregola.com/2016/02/07/how-to-build-a-rest-api-with-akka-http/

Comment: Depending on your backend server, you need to enable CORS, So have a check on your backend server and see how you could enable it!

Comment: Is there any reference for how to do it.

Comment: What is your backend server? Is it Play framework? Or Akka HTTP? What is it?

Comment: backend is akka http

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that i have to set the origin in my headers beside cors sittings as in back-end code

```
 $resource('http://localhost:8080/cart/:cartId',
 {cartId :'@cartId' },
 { update: { method: 'PUT' }},
 { headers : { 'Origin': 'http://localhost:8080' }} );
```